# What is OptionsParser doing in this case?

Tags: ruby

I'm going through a [tutorial](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/01/03/how-do-i-make-a-command-line-tool-in-ruby/) on OptionsParser in ruby. There is a line of code that I'm confused about:

```
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
.
.
.
server_list = %w[a b c]
opt.on("-s SERVERS","--servers SERVERS", server_list, "which server will start between #{server_list.join(',')}") do |servers|
  options[:servers] = servers
end
```

I understand that `OptionParser#on` can convert a value to a type defined for example:

```
.
.
.
opt.on("-e","--environment ENVIRONMENT",Numeric, "which environment you want server run") do |environment|
  puts environment #=> Fixnum
  options[:environment] = environment
end
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to successfully run a ruby program that uses OptionParser as shown above. See below for what I've tried.

```
➜  ruby-cli cat 04-with_optparse_convert_values
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'optparse'

options = {}

option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.banner = "Usage: cats"

  opt.on("-e", "--environment ENVIRONMENT", Numeric, "environment to run") do |env|
    puts "env.class"
    p env.class
    options[:environment] = env
  end

  opt.on("--delay N", Float, "Delay N seconds before executing") do |n|
    options[:delay] = n
  end

  opt.on("-j x,y,z","--jurisdictions x,y,z", Array,
  "which jurisdiction will start") do |jurisdictions|
    options[:jurisdictions] = jurisdictions
  end

  server_list = %w[a b c]
  opt.on("-s SERVERS","--servers SERVERS", server_list,
  "which server will start between #{server_list.join(',')}") do |servers|
    options[:servers] = servers
  end

end

option_parser.parse!
p options
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -j cats,and,dogs
{:jurisdictions=>["cats", "and", "dogs"]}
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -j cats,and,dogs -s cats,and,dogs
./04-with_optparse_convert_values:33:in `<main>': invalid argument: -s cats,and,dogs (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -j cats,and,dogs -s cats
./04-with_optparse_convert_values:33:in `<main>': invalid argument: -s cats (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -j cats,and,dogs -s "cats,and,dogs"
./04-with_optparse_convert_values:33:in `<main>': invalid argument: -s cats,and,dogs (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -j cats,and,dogs -s "cats\nand\ndogs"
./04-with_optparse_convert_values:33:in `<main>': invalid argument: -s cats\nand\ndogs (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
➜  ruby-cli ARRAY=(cats and dogs)
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -j cats,and,dogs -s ${ARRAY[\*]}
./04-with_optparse_convert_values:33:in `<main>': invalid argument: -s cats (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
➜  ruby-cli
```

Comment: If you defined valid servers as `["a", "b", "c"]`, why do you think `-s cats` would be appropriate? `-s a` should work (or `-s b`, or `-s c`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server_list = %w[a b c]
opt.on("-s SERVERS","--servers SERVERS", server_list,
"which server will start between #{server_list.join(',')}") do |servers|
  options[:servers] = servers
end
```

is providing an array of "servers" to choose from via the command line option `-s` so, `./04-with_optparse_convert_values -s cats` wouldn't work because it is not one of the choices, but `a`, `b`, or `c` will. For example:

```
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -s a
{:servers=>"a"}
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -s b
{:servers=>"b"}
➜  ruby-cli ./04-with_optparse_convert_values -s c
{:servers=>"c"}
```